# How can i restart app when i change language in react native

Tags: react-native, picker, i18n-js, react-native-localize

I tried to create a picker that is used to change language. But some texts remain untranslated even if user selects different language.  i tried

```js
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';
import I18n from 'i18n-js';
import memoize from 'lodash.memoize'; 

import en from './en';
import am from './am';
import or from './or';
import tg from './tg';


const locales = RNLocalize.getLocales();
if (Array.isArray(locales)) {
  I18n.locale = locales[0].languageTag;
}

I18n.translations = {
  default: en,
  'en-US': en,
  en,
  am,
  or,
  tg,

};

I18n.fallbacks = true;
export default I18n;
```

the Code I use to switch language is

```js
onChangeLanguage(languageSelected){
  this.setState({
    languageSelected
  })
  I18n.locale = languageSelected 
}
```

and the react native picker is:

```html
<Picker
  mode="dropdown"
  iosHeader={''} 
  style={{ width: width,height:80,}}
  selectedValue={this.props.language}
  onValueChange={this.props.onChangeLanguage.bind(this)}
>
  {listLanguage.map((languageItem, i) => {
      return <Picker.Item key={i} value={languageItem.key} label= {languageItem.label} />
  })}
</Picker>
```

Does any one show me how to Restart app when language is changed(selected)? Thanks

Comment: I have an idea, you could use [Asyncstorage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) to store the `locales[0].languageTag` and compare every time if it different what you get from storage, and then store the new one, then [restart app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489946/programmatically-restart-a-react-native-app)

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to switch between lanugages?

Comment: @ nipuna777 here is the code                       
first this.state {languageSelected:en}                                                                
 onChangeLanguage(languageSelected){
    this.setState({
      languageSelected
    })
       I18n.locale = languageSelected 
  }

Comment: How Do i use AsyncStorage i this senario and restart app @高鵬翔

Comment: I have seen in your code you already using react-native-restart, Is it making some problem?

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar i only imported react-native-restart , not used yet

Comment: @高鵬翔 Thanks for your answer. I don't know how to integrate what you have said in to  the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to restart your app after language change.
In React, the app re-renders if it is dependant on state or props changes.
You can check my answer here: [React Native, how to update view after language change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055467/react-native-how-to-update-view-after-language-change/65591520#65591520)

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart only if you change the flow's content. If the language you change to is `RTL`, you need to restart.

You could use `react-native-restart`.

You can check their npm page [from here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-restart).